# How would I write a T-SQL query to concatenate and group text

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with the following structure:

```
PERSON   Sequence    TEXT
  1        1         John ran
  1        2         across the field
  2        1         Bill also
  2        2         ran across the field after John
```

I would like to write a query that produces the following result:

```
 PERSON   TEXT
 1        John ran across the field
 2        Bill also ran across the field after John
```

Is something like this possible with T-SQL

Comment: Yes it is possible [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string) Probably person 3 should be 2

Comment: Yes, person 3 should be Person 2 - Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT PERSON, STUFF((SELECT ' ' + TEXT
    FROM [YourTable] a
    WHERE a.PERSON = b.PERSON
    ORDER BY PERSON,SEQUENCE
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as TEXT
FROM [YourTable] b
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick sketch:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ST2.person, 
    SUBSTRING(
        (
           SELECT ' '+ST1.[text]  AS [text()]
           FROM [dbo].[tab] ST1
           WHERE ST1.person = ST2.person
           ORDER BY ST1.person, ST1.sequence
           FOR XML PATH ('')
        ), 2, 1000) AS [text]
FROM [dbo].[tab] ST2
```

For anyone who wants to [play with it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b4811/5)